# Get an object from an array on predicate in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, match

I have the following array of objects :

```
var objs = [{id: 1, name: 'foo', ...},
            {id: 2, name: 'bar', ...},
            {id: 3, name: 'baz', ...}];
```

and this variable :

```
var matcher = 'bar';
```

What is the easiest way to get the *object* that has the `matcher` equals to its `name` ?

Using this `matcher` the result should be :

```
{id: 2, name: 'bar', ...}
```

Comment: @Vohuman your duplicate reference is old from '12. technos are evolving and new solutions are provided. Please before soiling my post, take time to act.

Comment: One of those answers suggests `$.grep`, Another one suggests`Array.prototype.filter`. Developers still use them. You just want to filter an object in array, a simple, very old `for` loop can do this too. There is no need to use a 2015 tech for it. And the point of marking as duplicate is not "soling" a question.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use `filter` function

```
var objs = [{id: 1, name: 'foo'},
            {id: 2, name: 'bar'},
            {id: 3, name: 'baz'}];

var matcher = 'bar';

var result = objs.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.name === matcher;
});

console.log(result); // [{id: 2, name: 'bar'}]
console.log(result[0]); // {id: 2, name: 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably using a library which allows some higher level functions on objects, such as `filter`.

Such libraries are for example underscore and lodash, both reserving the _ sign for use, with which you'd write:

```
_(objs).filter(function(element){return element.name === matcher})[0];
```

(The filter function returns the elements of an array or objects for which the given filtering function returns true - in this case, you're checking whether the name equals your matcher. The return value is an array of these elements, hence the [0] part)

**EDIT**: I didn't notice you had an array to begin with, then you don't even need an external library, arrays by default have the filter method on them.